# Generate one-hot vector from a nx1 array of binary labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have an array like this:

```
X = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

I want to create a one-hot encoder vector of nx2

```
one_hotX = [[1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1],[1,0]...]
```

Is there an easy way to do this? OneHotEncoder and LabelEncoder don't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

How about constructing the vector by yourself:

```
[[0, 1] if i else [1, 0] for i in X]

#[[1, 0],
# [1, 0],
# [0, 1],
# [0, 1],
# [1, 0],
# [1, 0],
# [0, 1],
# [0, 1],
# [0, 1],
# [1, 0],
# [1, 0],
# [1, 0]]
```

If you are working with `numpy`, you could do something such as this as well(vectorized approach):

```
import numpy as np
code = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
arrX = np.array(X)

code[arrX]

#array([[1, 0],
#       [1, 0],
#       [0, 1],
#       [0, 1],
#       [1, 0],
#       [1, 0],
#       [0, 1],
#       [0, 1],
#       [0, 1],
#       [1, 0],
#       [1, 0],
#       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: @ayhan Indeed. `X` doesn't need to be an array.